# Is there a more idiomatic way to get N random elements of a collection in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, idioms

I’m currrently doing this: `(repeatedly n #(rand-nth (seq coll)))` but I suspect there might be a more idiomatic way, for 2 reasons:

- I’ve found that there’s frequently a more concise and expressive alternative to using short anonymous functions, e.g. `partial`
- the docstring for `repeatedly` says “presumably with side effects”, implying that it’s not intended to be used to produce values

I suppose I could figure out a way to use `reduce` but that seems like it would be tricky and less efficient, as it would have to process the entire collection, since `reduce` is not lazy.

Comment: Your code is okay if you want possible duplicates, *except* you might consider working on a vector instead of a sequence so that you do not incur linear time lookup for each `nth`.

Comment: Note that the bit about "presumably with side effects" is applicable here. The call to `rand-nth` has the side effect of altering the state of the random number generator. If there were no side effects, then each call would return the same result, so presumably you wouldn't need to call it multiple times.

Comment: “presumably with side effects” does not imply it should not be used to produce values. It just implies that if your function is pure (no side-effects) then you'll get n times the same value. So `repeatedly` is only useful when the function is not pure -- and rand fns are not pure so everything is ok with your code.

Comment: Something is wrong with your code though: you call `seq` on coll, thus turning the coll in a sequence. It implies that `nth` is now going to take linear time (and chances are that `count` too). On a big collection it's going to degrade performance a lot. Better to convert to a vector (using `vec`) and to hoist the resulting vector out of the closure (so as to not convert it each time). One way to hoist it out is to use a good old `let`. The other is to use `partial`. `(repeatedly n (partial rand-nth (vec coll)))`

Comment: @cgrand insightful, thank you!!

Comment: I'm curious if @barracel's answer solved your problem (and was worth a checkmark). It was certainly what I was looking for, anyway. :)

Comment: @JohnC sorry, this was 2.5 years ago so I just don’t remember. Looking this over now, I think I prefer @cgrand’s suggestion above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy solution but not optimal for big collections could be:

```
(take n (shuffle coll))
```

Has the "advantage" of not repeating elements. Also you could implement a lazy-shuffle but it will involve more code.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not exactly what you're asking - but if you're doing a lot of sampling and statistical work, you might be interested in Incanter (`[incanter "1.5.2"]`).
Incanter provides the function `sample`, which provides options for sample size, and replacement.

```
(require '[incanter.stats :refer [sample]]))

(sample [1 2 3 4 5 6 7] :size 5 :replacement false) 
; => (1 5 6 2 7)
```